# Exchange/Outlook - How to make mail account always send mail to an additional pre-configured recipient?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I want to configure a mail account so, whenever it sends a mail to user1@test.com or anyone else, it also sends a mail to user2@test.com.

Preferably configured through Exchange so it will work for our third party applications that communicate with the exchange server, instead of a mail app.

is there a way to do this?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's you Exchange Server version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a transport rule on your Exchange server. There are wizards for it, it's quite easy. Just look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124737(v=exchg.141).aspx)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, the answer is "transport rules", can't really quote something from the page as it covers everything, from the basics to advanced features.